# Can't make requests by proxies python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, proxy, python-requests

I am Trying to make a request using proxy and i don't know why i

```
loadproxy = {
    "https":"114.99.11.114:3000",
    "http":"114.99.11.114:3000",
}

url = "http://httpbin.org/ip"

res = requests.get(url,proxies=loadproxy)


print(res.text)
```

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 502, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='114.99.11.114', port=3000): Max retries exceeded with url: http://httpbin.org/ip (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',)))

I Don't know why it is working acc to error the proxy is not working but i have changed a lot of proxy looking for help

One More Detain to add that while i am changing the proxy and i changed it and my code looks li

```
loadproxy = {
    "https":"118.69.50.154:80",
    "http":"118.69.50.154:80",
}

url = "http://httpbin.org/ip"

res = requests.get(url,proxies=loadproxy)


print(res.text)
```

but the problem here is it is showing my original ip

{
  "origin": "my_ip"
}

and even the proxy is anonymous

Comment: I've not checked if your `<ipaddress>:<port>` combo is a valid proxy but it is definitely missing the protocol. E.e. `"https":"https://114.99.11.114:3000"` instead of `"https":"114.99.11.114:3000"`

Comment: No I Tried it but it is not making any effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print(requests.get("http://httpbin.org/ip",proxies={"http":"http://118.69.50.154:80"}).text)
```

worked for me and produced:

```
{
    "origin": "210.245.110.254"  
}
```

which is definitely not my IP.